# Tree content provider in eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I would like to create the tree of projects and packages on one of the pages of wizard (similar to the tree in 'move' option in eclipse). It's not difficult how to create the tree, but the problem is that I need to have this structure of available projects and packages which I'm not sure how I can get.
This is my first post here so if I was not clear enough, I will provide more details.
Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/ui/StandardJavaElementContentProvider.html shows Java element hierarchy.